# C# red cross in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

i am using c# and when i try to fill my datagridView most of the time a big red cross apears.

i searched for this and people say that you have to add

```
public class SafeDataGridView : DataGridView
{
   protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
   {
      try
      {
        base.OnPaint(e);
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
        this.Invalidate();
      }
   }
}
```

i tried to just add this in a simple class file but that did not do anything.

Comment: What did they say you should add?

Comment: exactly whats inside the code box

Comment: and what code are you using to fil the grid?

Comment: portos_online.DataSource = content; and content is a datatable with content from a database.

Comment: You must add this not as a simple class file only, but the instance of your control must be of type SafeDataGridView. then this code will execute.

Comment: The red cross usually means that the content can't be rendered. What exactly is the content? Bitmap, text or what..?

Comment: the red cross i found out is because the data changed while painting and the data is all text they are just plain database results, and how do you do that @kpa6uk

Comment: In YourForm.Designer.cs look for string `gridView = new DataGridView()` and replace it with `gridView = new SafeDataGridView()`

Comment: private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView portos_online; <- ?

Comment: oh yes, sorry for mistake, this too

Comment: `private SafeDataGridView portos_online;` and `portos_online = new SafeDataGridView();`

Comment: please put it as an answer so i can select it as the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In YourForm.Designer.cs look for string `gridView = new DataGridView()` and replace it with

`gridView = new SafeDataGridView()`

`private SafeDataGridView portos_online;`

`portos_online = new SafeDataGridView();`

I hope this will solve your problem. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

[Same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746507/c-sharp-datagridview-red-cross/30073284#30073284). Use Invoke method

```
if (gridView.InvokeRequired)
    gridView.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => gridView.DataSource = YOUR_DATASOURCE));
else
    gridView.DataSource = YOUR_DATASOURCE;
```