# c# datagridview red cross

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datatable

I have a datagridview and datatable. I use the datatable as a datasource of the datagridview. I add and update the data using threads as below. And if I am done with the data I remove it. But two times there were **big red x** in front of the datagridview. I couldn't find out why? Below are my sample.

**Note:** This does not always occur, I got this error only two times but I need to handle! Thanks in advance.

```
  Thread listData;
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  Form1_load()
  {
    dataGridview.DataSource = dt;
  }

   public void ListData()
   {
      foreach(var item in data)
      {
          if(item.delete)
          { 
            var row = dt.Rows.Find(item.id); 
            if(row != null) { row.Delete();}
            continue;
          }

          listData = new Thread(delegate() { InsertOrUpdateData(item.Id); });
           listData.Start(); listData.Join();
       }

   }

      public void InserOrUpdateData(int id)
      {
         // Here I retrieve some data from database
         // and insert or update to the datatable
          // like dt.Rows.Add(fields) and dt.Rows.Find(id)["fieldName"] = "new Value"
      }
```

Comment: Are you handling some custom painting? It will happen when there is an unhandled exception occurs while painting the control.

Comment: If you ask if I have a method to paint something, I dont. I populate all data as I showed above. There is already a working datagridview on my form. I add the data only to the datatable.

Comment: I don't think you can be updating that datatable in a thread if it's bound to a control.  Retrieve the data, then invoke the results to the UI thread: that's where you then add the row to the data table.  Otherwise, you would have to show more code than you are for us to help you.

Comment: @LarsTech You're right. I overlooked creation of thread. That's most likely the problem.

Comment: Besides the code I showed, I add columns (dt.Columns.Add())and a primary key to the datatable. After that I only add,update and remove the rows from the datatable. I have nothing more.

Comment: But it looks like you are doing that in a thread.  You can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30073256/1019435) method

```
if (gridView.InvokeRequired)
    gridView.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => gridView.DataSource = YOUR_DATASOURCE));
else
    gridView.DataSource = YOUR_DATASOURCE;
```