# Datagrid view cell formatting issue in windows C# application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I have load the data grid view dynamically from sql database. In that based on particular column value, i have to change the background color of the cell.

[image]

but it is displayed like this,

```
private void Grid_Log_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Set the background to red for negative values in the Balance column.
            if (Grid_Log.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("MStatus") || Grid_Log.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Status"))
            {
                if (e.Value.Equals("SUCCESS")||e.Value.Equals("Closed"))
                {
                    //e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    //e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                    //Grid_Log.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    Grid_Log.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
```

i have tried above code but still its occurs.

Comment: I think you should take a look at this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994457/c-sharp-red-cross-in-datagridview

Comment: Your posted code will change the background color to red if the columns `MStatus` value is “SUCCESS” OR will change the background to red if the columns `Status` value is “Closed”. You should be checking for the possibility that `e.Value` may be null. I am not sure what the picture is supposed to represent, a cell or the whole grid?

Comment: Thank you johnG, I have fixed it.it is occurs when e.Value is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Grid_Log_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Grid_Log.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("MStatus") || Grid_Log.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Status"))
            {
                if (e.Value!=null)
                {
                    if (e.Value.Equals("SUCCESS") || e.Value.Equals("Closed"))
                    {
                        //e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        //e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                        //Grid_Log.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        Grid_Log.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```